# Do you need to configure Constraints, Indices, Default Values, etc. when working with an existing database in EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I usually define my databases in pure SQL (most of the time in VS Database Projects) and if I need to use them in .NET project I [reverse engineer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) them with Entity Framework.

But if you generate your entities and context from an existing database you usually end up with a bunch of code that just configures things I don't want to have handled by EF anyways like Indices.

Is all of that code really needed for Entity Framework to run properly? Or is it just there in case somebody would want to use migrations or other things from EF? What is the bare minimum of configuration needed to work without problems?

A few examples of code that seems unnecessary to me (all for EF Core):

**Constraints and Delete Behavior**

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.Order)
    .WithMany(p => p.OrderPosition)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrderId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull) // ?
    .HasConstraintName("FK_ORDER_ORDERPOSITION"); // ?
```

**Default Values and ColumnTypes**

```
entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
    .HasColumnType("datetime") // ?
    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())"); // ?

entity.Property(e => e.Price)
    .HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)"); // ?
```

**Indices**

```
entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.ProjectId, e.OrderId }) // ?
    .HasName("UNIQUE_PROJECT_ORDER") // ?
    .IsUnique(); // ?
```

**MaxLength**

```
entity.Property(e => e.Application)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(60); // ?
```

**Value Generation**

```
entity.Property(e => e.Sequence)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); // ?

entity.Property(e => e.GUID)
    .ValueGeneratedNever(); // ?
```

Comment: I'd say it's subjective: It depends on how you use it. For example, let's say you only use EF to read data, then you don't care about setting MaxLength, but you probably care about relationships (simplistic example, I know.)

Answer (score 2):

Most of this is either used, or useful.  EF would work without all this, but you can run into issues or limitations.

ColumnTypes and lengths is needed for EF to properly bind parameters.  The Key generation strategy needs to be known to EF to fetch generated key values.  EF needs to understand the relationship between Navigation Properties and Foreign Key Properties.

I don't think EF does anything with the cascading behavior of relationships, but it might, or might in the future.

EF doesn't care about indexes, but might in the future be aware of unique indexes.  And EF Core needs to know about all keys involved in Foreign Key relationships.

Comment: Also, only configuration that differs from the configuration that would be created by convention is code generated.

Comment: It uses the cascading behavior. It mimics it on the client side for loaded entities.

Answer (score 0):

The following are *currently* unused by the runtime (outside of Migrations) and can be safely removed from the scaffolded code:

- Sequences
- Constraint names
- Non-unique indexes
- Index filters